# Trying to find the specific issue/issue number of a Marvel comic that feature a bonus story of Dr. Strange vs. Loki

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, doctor-strange

**Plot Details/Summary**

This particularly story was sort of a "bonus" story at the end of another Marvel comic.  It may have been a Marvel Double Feature, but I don't think it was.  I *think* it was tacked on to an Avengers comic, but that may not be the case.

The story is short, but quite clever, with Loki in his spirit form tricking Dr. Strange into stealing Thor's hammer.  The deception is uncovered and the two have a very entertaining mystical battle. Despite only having a fraction of his full power in his spirit form, Loki is clearly far more powerful than Strange, and would have destroyed him except Thor manages to close in and Loki flees.

I have been able to find screen shots of the story online, but none of my Google-fu has turned up the comic it originally came from.  I'm trying to find what comic it came from.   It's not Strange Tales 182. I'm certain the story was attached to another comic.

[image]

[image]

**Publication Details/Timeframe**

Mid-to-late 1970s, unquestionably. Something ticking over in my mind suggests it may have been in an issue where Hank Pym (as Giant Man) was going through his "stuck in 10 foot form" in the primary story, but I could be way off on that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Notice that [Strange Tales #182](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Strange_Tales_Vol_1_182) is a reprint of [Strange Tales #123](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Strange_Tales_Vol_1_123)

[image: Strange Tales 123 cover]

The costume used by Strange in your images corresponds to the one depicted in the original cover. And the style of those pictures looks like Ditko to me.

Moreover, in the linked page you can find what seems a description of one of the vignettes present in your post, **including the editor's note**

> Doctor Strange threatens to trap Loki in the **Purple Dimension**, which Strange first visited in **Strange Tales #119**.

In [this page](https://marvelousage.com/2018/09/17/strange-tales-vol-1-123/) you can find an entry dedicated to such issue. It includes some of your referenced panels.

[image: Image from Strange Tales 123]

Comment: That has to be the correct issue.  It doesn't ring with how I remember coming across the story, but that was 40+ years ago and your answer fits in every other way.  I must have mis-remembered how I first read it.